# Why does Android double up Imagesizes in an ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

I loaded an jpg image (Size 1450x1027) as a drawable to an Android ImageView and store height and width of the loaded image in variables like this:

```
myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture1);

int width = mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
int height = mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
```

I am wondering now, why the values of width is 2900 and height is 2054 . So why does Android double up the sizes of the jpg ?

Comment: What folder are you putting the image in to?

Comment: it's simply in "res\drawable"  , not in a specific dpi subfolder

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are using getIntrinsticWidth or height which doesn't get the actual dimensions (or properties in general) of the image but rather the dimensions of the Drawable defined in your xml layout.

getWidth and height should get the actual properties of the image.

Comment: You mean something like this ? :

   `Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) ImageView.this.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    int w = b.getWidth();  
    int h = b.getHeight();`

Well it's the same result :-(